# Port C++ i_pwCalculateCRC16Continuation to C#

Tags: c#, c++

How to correctly convert the following C++ into C#?

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Calculate a 16-bit Cycle Redundency Check (CRC) value on a block of //data.
//
// Params:
// pData : Pointer to data to calculate CRC.
// dwSize : Size of data in bytes.
//
// Return:
// 16-bit CRC value.
//
// Notes:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
private WORD i_pwCalculateCRC16Continuation(PBYTE pData, WORD dwSize, WORD wCRC)
{
    // high byte of CRC initialized
    BYTE cCRCHi = (BYTE) ((wCRC >> 8) & 0xFF);
    // low byte of CRC initialized
    BYTE cCRCLo = (BYTE) (wCRC & 0xFF);
    // will index into CRC lookup table
    BYTE cIndex;    
    while (dwSize--) // step through each byte of data
    {
        cIndex = cCRCHi ^ *pData++; // calculate the CRC
        cCRCHi = cCRCLo ^ m_cCRCHiArray[cIndex];
        cCRCLo = m_cCRCLoArray[cIndex];
    }
    return (cCRCHi << 8) + cCRCLo;
}
```

I found a tool that converted it but it were not perfect and it does not understand the context.

```
private ushort i_pwCalculateCRC16Continuation(ref byte pData, ushort dwSize, ushort wCRC)
{
    byte cCRCHi = (byte) ((wCRC >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byte cCRCLo = (byte) (wCRC & 0xFF);
    byte cIndex;

    while (dwSize-- > 0)
    {
        // Cannot convert source type 'int' to target type 'byte'
        cIndex = cCRCHi ^ pData++;
        // Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'byte'
        cCRCHi = cCRCLo ^ m_cCRCHiArray[cIndex];
        // Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'byte'
        cCRCLo = m_cCRCLoArray[cIndex];
    }
    // Cannot convert expression type 'int' to return type 'ushort'
    return (cCRCHi << 8) + cCRCLo;
}
```

The CRC concept and bit wise operations are little bit unfamiliar for me and I do not understand the above code well. Hence I do not know how to "fix" it.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Missed the following variables.

```
private static byte[] m_cCRCHiArray = {
    0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,  0x81, 0x40
};

private static byte[] m_cCRCLoArray = {
    0x00, 0xC0, 0xC1, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x03, 0x02, 0xC2, 0x80, 0x40
};
```

Comment: Whilst I can't comment on general problems (I'm too lazy to run your code!) the most obvious issue is that `pData` in the C++ code is a buffer, not simply a pointer to a single byte value. The length of the buffer is presumably stored in dwSize. Your C# code should take either a) a `byte[] data` array, or b) `Stream dataStream, int countBytes`. Your member variable `m_cCRCHiArray` also needs to be an array of bytes.

Comment: What would pData incrementation (pData++) mean if pData is a byte array? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Under C and C++, you can iterate over a C-style array by repeatedly incrementing a pointer to it. This would not work under C#. If `pData` were a C# array, your loop would look more like `for (int i = 0; i < pData.Length; i++) { cIndex = cCRCHi ^ pData[dataIndex++]; // etc`

Comment: Incidentally, apologies if I'm repeating either C or C# stuff to you with which you are already familiar!

Comment: No need to apology. This is just what I need to understand the C++ workings - a C++ and C# code comparison.

Comment: For some reason in C# bitwise XOR cCRCLo ^ m_cCRCHiArray[cIndex] will result in an int not byte as the code expects. Is it safe to cast/convert it into a byte?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is safe to cast it to byte. I can't actually think of any good reason for making the result an int, so maybe its just another one of those increasingly bizarre C# language features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static byte[] m_cCRCHiArray = { 
    0x00, 0xC1, 0x81, 0x40, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x41,  0x81, 0x40 
};

private static byte[] m_cCRCLoArray = { 
    0x00, 0xC0, 0xC1, 0x01, 0xC3, 0x03, 0x02, 0xC2, 0x80, 0x40 
};

private ushort i_pwCalculateCRC16Continuation(byte[] data, ushort wCRC)
{
    byte cCRCHi = (byte)((wCRC >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byte cCRCLo = (byte)(wCRC & 0xFF);

    byte cIndex;

    for (int i=0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        cIndex = (byte)(cCRCHi ^ data[i]);
        cCRCHi = (byte)(cCRCLo ^ m_cCRCHiArray[cIndex]);
        cCRCLo = m_cCRCLoArray[cIndex];
    }

    return (byte)((cCRCHi << 8) + cCRCLo);
}
```

It isn't obviously wrong at first glance ;-)

I've not altered any of the hungarian notation, except for changing `pData` to `data`

Comment: Syntax is correct. Now I will take some time to set up the test case and see if the actual result it produces is correct. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I knew what for the wCRC parameter is and what should the value be. I know that I need to get CRC low and high values.

Comment: If you look at the very end of [this pdf](http://www.clarityvisual.com/partners/common/docs/techresources/Bobcat/070-0108-01_Bobcat_I_RS232.pdf) you'll see that they start their CRC computation with 0xFFFF. This appears to be the same code as you are using, so it would be a sensible appropach to take, perhaps.

Comment: Yes the code seems to be the same and the command structure is also similar (magic packets, payload size, CRC are at the same locations). Just the Bobcats are not my fields but it has better specifications then I currently have.

Comment: I guess the return value should be ushort instead of byte. Still have not got expected result. Must be input error.